# How can i log response code from server

Tags: php, logging, curl, nginx, response

i need to log the response header/code from the server?
How can i do this? With NginX or with PHP/Curl?

An example:
(This i the request from the client)

```
 ----------------Request-------------------------
 GET /download.php?request=abc123xyz&link=http%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.com%2Fwatch?v=pRPOztxXWlQ HTTP/1.1
 Host: api.example.com
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Pragma: no-cache
 Accept-Language: de, en-gb;q=0.9, en;q=0.8
 Accept: application/json
 User-Agent: JDownloader
```

Answer from my Server (Response Code/Header)

```
 ----------------Response Information------------
 Connection-Time: keep-Alive
 ----------------Response------------------------
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: nginx
 Date: Fri, 28 Nov 2014 12:03:32 GMT
 Content-Type: application/json
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Connection: keep-alive
 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
 X-Frame-Options: DENY
 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 ------------------------------------------------
```

I need this, because i have sometimes problems with the download of different files. My service downloads videos from some streamhoster like youtube. The output of the response code helps me to know if this a problem with my server or with the external downloader (JDownloader, Load!, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Add header content in your access log with `$http_<my_header>` variables where `<my_header>` is the desired header name in lower can with dashes replaced by underscores. For instance `X-Frame-Options` could be logged with `$http_x_frame_options` added to access **[logformat](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)**.